# Random large floating point errors and NaN when using a recursive function in Fortran

Tags: function, recursion, fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I am trying to create a foil section using b-splines and a recursive function. The problem is that it returns some of the values in either very large floating point numbers or NaN and even infinity sometimes. Which of the values seems to change after recompiling and sometimes more than others for some reason. The values it does return normally are correct.

Does anyone have any suggestion what the problem might be? Any help is much appreciated. I know my code here is quite long, but I think everything is necessary. First is the program and next the module with subroutines and the function.

The correct answer should be:
    `xb = 0    0.0147    0.0529    0.1063    0.1675    0.2448

    0.3564    0.5202    0.7231    0.9047    1.0000` and
`yb = 0   -0.0088   -0.0166   -0.0227   -0.0264   -0.0272 -0.0245   -0.0178   -0.0084   -0.0009         0`

```
module splines
     IMPLICIT NONE

     interface CoxdeBoor
        module procedure CoxdeBoor
     end interface CoxdeBoor


CONTAINS    

SUBROUTINE Splinefoil(N, degree, params, pts, xb, yb)
    INTEGER :: degree, N, i, pts
    REAL :: Pxb(pts+2), Pyb(pts+2)
    REAL :: tegap
    REAL, dimension (:):: yb, xb, params
    tegap=0.00; 

    Pxb(1:2)=0
    Pyb(1)=0
    DO i=1, pts-1
        !x-coordinates of bottom
        Pxb(i+2)=params(((2*i)-1)+2*pts)
        !y-coordinates of bottom
        Pyb(i+1)=params(2*i-2+2*pts)
    END DO
    Pyb(pts+1)=params(4*pts-2)
    Pxb(pts+2)=1
    Pyb(pts+2)=-0.5*tegap

    call Bspline(N,degree,Pxb, Pyb, pts,xb,yb)
END SUBROUTINE Splinefoil 

SUBROUTINE Bspline(N, degree, Px, Py, pts, x, y)
    INTEGER :: degree, N, j, i, n1, pts, l
    INTEGER, parameter :: len=10
    REAL :: B(pts+2), Qx(N/2+1), Qy(N/2+1), t(N/2+1), dt
    REAL, dimension(1:len) :: T2
    REAL, dimension (:):: Px, Py, y, x 
    n1=pts+1

    DO i=1, degree+n1+2
        IF (i<(degree+2)) THEN
            T2(i)=0
        ELSE IF (((degree+2) <= i) .and. (i < (n1 +2))) THEN
            T2(i)=(i-degree-1)/real((n1+1-degree))
        ELSE
            T2(i)=1
        END IF
    END DO

    t(1)=0
    dt=1/real((N/2))
    DO j=1, N/2
        t(j+1)=t(j) + dt 
    END DO
    Qx(1)=0
    DO l=1, N/2+1
        DO i=0, n1
            B(i+1)= CoxdeBoor(degree,i+1, T2,t(l))
            x(l)=x(l) + B(i+1) * Px(i+1)
        END DO
    END DO

    DO l=1, N/2+1
        DO i=0, n1
            B(i+1)= CoxdeBoor(degree,i+1, T2,t(l))
            y(l)=y(l) + B(i+1) * Py(i+1)
        END DO
    END DO  
END SUBROUTINE Bspline

RECURSIVE FUNCTION CoxdeBoor(i, j, x, t) result(val)
    INTEGER :: i, j, m
    REAL :: val, t, t1, t2
    REAL, dimension(:) :: x
    m=10
    IF (i==0) THEN
        IF (x(j)<=t .and. t<x(j+1)) THEN
            val=1
        ELSE IF (x(j)<=t .and. t==x(j+1) .and. x(j+1)==1) THEN
            val=1
        ELSE
            val=0
        END IF
        ELSE
        IF (x(j)<x(j+i)) THEN
            t1 =CoxdeBoor(i-1,j,x,t)
            val=(t - x(j)) / (x(j+i) - x(j)) * t1
        ELSE
            val=0
         END IF
        IF (j<m) THEN
            IF (x(j+1)<x(j+i+1)) THEN
                t2 =CoxdeBoor(i-1,j+1,x,t)
                 val=val + (x(j+i+1) - t) / (x(j+i+1) - x(j+1)) * t2
            END IF
        END IF
     END IF
END FUNCTION CoxdeBoor

END MODULE splines

Program TEST
     USE splines
     implicit none
     INTEGER, parameter :: N=20, pts=4
     INTEGER :: degree, i
     REAL :: params(14), xb(N/2+1), yb(N/2+1), xt(N/2+1), yt(N/2+1), x(N+1), y(N+1)

     params=(/0.010021287940814, 0.069234038308141, 0.039810312675194, 0.602154240414724, 0.027370571639440, 0.705186051614965,&
         0.015116139770247, -0.010144644178286, 0.119067997228366, -0.028919194962962, 0.338791094291084, -0.028735107857216,&
         0.965914604459008, 0.004397962157839/)

     degree =3

     call Splinefoil(N, degree, params, pts, xt, yt)

     write(*,*) xt
     write(*,*) yt
     OPEN(4, FILE='foil3.dat')
     WRITE(4, '(2F10.4)') (xt(i), yt(i), i=1, 11)
     CLOSE(4)
END PROGRAM TEST
```

Comment: My guess if you've forgotten to initialize a variable somewhere. Perhaps somebody here can find it for you, but there are lots of tools which can help. To start, have you used your compilers run-time checks? (ifort check-uninit, for example)

Comment: Did you know that one `implicit none` per module is sufficient? Also it is not a good idea to use unit number `4`, use larger numbers.

Comment: I tried to make your indentation a bit more consistent. It could still be improved, but that would be too much work. I second the suggestion to compile with all debugging flags you can find in your compiler (`gfortran -g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall` or even `gfotran -g -fsanitize=address,undefined`).

Comment: If I read your code correctly the 3rd argument in the call to `coxdeboor` is a 10-element rank-1 array but the function declares it to have 11 elements.  I may well read your code incorrectly, but the way you have written it, with explicit sizes for argument arrays, makes it very vulnerable to errors arising from walking off the end of an array.  'Random' behaviour such as you report is a typical consequence.  Far better to use *assumed shape* arrays, well covered in many SO Qs and As, and in documentation too I think.

Comment: Thanks for al the info guys. @VladimirF I know the code looks a bit dodgy, it used to have a cleaner look, I started changing things while frustrated, not good! I use all the flags while compiling already, i forgot to mention that. I am sorry to ask but what is unit number 4?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark You were right, it should have 10 elements. I changed it and the arrays are now assumed arrays as you said. The behaviour is still the same unfortunately.

Comment: Unit number 4 is the `open(4, file=`). But it does not cause your current problem. Still it is not good. 5 and 6 are definitely bad.

Comment: @VladimirF Ah thanks will change that!

Comment: Your arrays are still all explicit shape.  You (to follow High Performance Mark's comment) want to use declarations like `dimension(:)`.

Comment: @francescalus I tried that but I get the following error: `Error: Array ‘t2’ at (1) cannot have a deferred shape` It might be clear by know I am not a really experienced coder unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, only the dummy arguments can be specified like that.  `t2` is a local variable in `Bspline`.  `Px`, `Py`, `x` and `y` from that subroutine are eligible to be assumed shape.

Comment: @francescalus I see the difference, thanks! I changed my code accordingly. Still the same behaviour though.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to deviate from the useful comment thread above. Here are my two cents on the issue - I recompiled your code with `gfortran` (using Codeblocks, not that it matters). I agree that enabling the available compiler flags does not help pinpoint the issue. Initially it looked like there was a bound-checking issue (you are referring to a memory block outside the bounds of an array, which is not initialised), but that was not the case.

HOWEVER - I turned on the following flags for the compiler:

```
-ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow,underflow,inexact,denormal
```

In Codeblocks you can do this in `Project>Build Options>Other Compiler Options` and add this manually (I imagine it would be similar in other IDEs). What it does is that it raises an error when an erroneous floating-point operation is encountered (division by zero, a number outside the value range specified by your variable type etc.). Such issues can cause any number of problems in your program - from significantly slowing down performance (e.g. `denormal` which interrupts the calculation process until the CPU figures out how to round/represent the denormal number) to giving you outright wrong results (`zero` giving you `NaN`s).

Using the debugging tools you can now go through and remedy these in your program. For more information on this flag and other strategies for hunting down numerical errors in your program check out [this GFortran manual section](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Debugging-Options.html). Good luck error hunting!